# Angular material stepper labels on left side

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

I am buidling an application with angular and its material library. When I am using angular stepper it usually look like this
[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhALT.png)
But i want it to look like this
[Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLA7s.png)
and stepper content on the right..

I tried some css but it is not changing..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.